# handler on a recursive function

Tags: java, android, runnable, android-handler

In one activity I have this recursive method:

```
private void startThread(final int i){

    if(i < length){
        TaskCross taskCross = new TaskCross();
        TaskScreenshot taskScreenshot = new TaskScreenshot(i);
        TaskNoise taskNoise = new TaskNoise();
        TaskEditText taskEditText = new TaskEditText();

        handler.postDelayed(taskCross, 1000);
        handler.postDelayed(taskScreenshot, 2000);
        handler.postDelayed(taskNoise, 2100);
        handler.postDelayed(taskEditText, 3000);

        myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                System.out.println("KEY ENTER!!!!!");
                if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    if(myEditText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserire un numero da 1 a 9", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString()) >= 1 &&
                            Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString()) <= 9){
                        startThread(i+1);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }       
        });
    }
}
```

And let's say the value of the variable `length` is `5`; the order that results is:

```
TaskCross
TaskScreenshot(0)
TaskNoise
TaskEditText

TaskCross
TaskCross
TaskScreenshot(1)
TaskScreenshot(2)
TaskNoise
TaskNoise
TaskEditText
TaskEditText

TaskCross
TaskCross
TaskScreenshot(3)
TaskScreenshot(4)
TaskNoise
TaskNoise
TaskEditText
TaskEditText
```

But the result that I want is this:

```
TaskCross
TaskScreenshot(0)
TaskNoise
TaskEditText

TaskCross
TaskScreenshot(1)
TaskNoise
TaskEditText

TaskCross
TaskScreenshot(2)
TaskNoise
TaskEditText

TaskCross
TaskScreenshot(3)
TaskNoise
TaskEditText

TaskCross
TaskScreenshot(4)
TaskNoise
TaskEditText
```

`TaskEditText` is a class that extends `Runnable`; this class collapse an `ImageView` and shows an `EditText`. In this `EditText` when a user press the Enter key of the keyboard the method is called recursively.

The first call of the method is `startThread(0)`

So, my question is: what am I doing wrong in this method? Am I using the `postDelayed` method in the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you enter into the world of `Thread`s, you cannot expect things run as if you had just one thread. Things run paralelly, and that means that by default they will run as they are, that means, first that processes something is the first to spit a result.

You can, however, change that behavior by exclusively blocking instances or even methods, so noone can touch a structure or enter a method until the thread working with them releases the instance or the method. That would be the `synchronized`'s case, you will be able to find more info [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html). Use that with extremely caution and you'll also need to know exactly when to use it, otherwise you'll most probably run into a deadlock.

**Note**: I'd not use threads and handlers within recursive functions if you plan using `synchronized` blocks. It's better using loops.

Comment: I've tried to add `synchronized` but the result is always the same; so I will try with a loop

Comment: Definitely the combination `synchronized` + recursion is a very bad combination. If you expect sequential results, can't you simply avoid using threads in your case? If not, probably there's another blocking tool that could help you with that: `CountDownLatch` http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: Yes, I can try to avoid threads, but I don't know how; anyway I will try to use `CountDownLatch`.